# How do I get each reduce task's execution time programmatically in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop

I am running a simple map reduce jobs in hadoop, in java i can calculate start time and end time using `System.currentTimeInMillis()` functions, in mapreduce how do i get this functionality to be done for map (endTime-startTime), reduce (endTime-startTime). I tried following code.. and i `set job.setNumReduceTasks(4)`

**Edited:**

```
public void reduce(Text _key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // process values
        long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
        int sum=0;

        for (IntWritable val : values) {

            sum+=val.get();

        }
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(_key, result);
        long end=System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println(" time Taken "+(end-start));


    }
```

but the result was:

```
time Taken 1
 time Taken 0
 time Taken 0
 time Taken 0
 time Taken 0
 time Taken 0
 time Taken 0
 time Taken 0
 time Taken 0
 time Taken 0
 ----------
 ----------
```

but i set number of reduce task to 4.. and it is showing here time taken to execute each key value pair..

After adding setup() method and cleanup() method..

```
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        start=System.currentTimeMillis();
        setup(context);
        try {
          while (context.nextKey()) {
            reduce(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getValues(), context);
          }
        } finally {
          cleanup(context);
          end=System.currentTimeMillis();
          System.out.println(" End- Start : "+(end-start));
        }
      }

    public void reduce(Text _key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int sum=0;

        for (IntWritable val : values) {

            sum+=val.get();

        }
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(_key, result);

    }
```

I have set  number of reducer to 4 using `job.setNumReduceTasks(4)`. but it is showing one timestamp only.. am i doing anything wrong here...

Comment: Why can't you do the same in your `map()` and `reduce()` methods?

Comment: @Jeremy, i have edited

Comment: Are you looking for the total time of the reducer, or each `reduce()` call?

Comment: If there are 4 reducers , then i am looking for, execution time of each one reducer.

Answer (score 0):

To find the total time of a reducer you can:

1. Add a `long` variable to the class that will hold the start time.
2. Set the start time in the [`setup()`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html#setup(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context)) method of the reducer.
3. Get the end time in the [`cleanup()`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html#cleanup(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context)) method of the reducer, and subtract from the stored start time to get the total time.

Comment: thanks for reply, i have edited above... I am not getting time of execution for each reduce task.

Comment: You will get one output per reducer log - make sure you check the logs for each of the four reducers.